Informix PrepareStatement throws error - "A character to numeric conversion process failed" when LIMIT clause is added to query
I have a sql query which works fine until a LIMIT clause is added to the end of the query.Below is the query:
String query = SELECT * FROM customer
WHERE acct = ?
  AND cust_id = ?  
  AND call_status = ?
  AND entry_id = get_user_id(?)
  AND cust_call_id = ?
  AND severity = ? 
LIMIT ?;

I am using PreparedStatement to set the values using Informix driver this is the complete class name: com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.
PreparedStatement pstmt = pstmt = m_con.prepareStatement(query);

There are no errors when operations like setString(), setInt() are done. Using setInt() when adding value for "?" for the LIMIT. I have checked multiple times and the correct values are set to the respective "?" . It throws an error when this line executes: pstmt.executeQuery()
Error trace:
A character to numeric conversion process failed
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildExceptionWithMessage(IfxErrMsg.java:416)
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildIsamException(IfxErrMsg.java:401)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.addException(IfxSqli.java:3021)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3272)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2269)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2194)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.sendStatementQuery(IfxSqli.java:1524)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeStatementQuery(IfxSqli.java:1474)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.executeQuery(IfxResultSet.java:183)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeQueryImpl(IfxStatement.java:902)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.executeQuery(IfxPreparedStatement.java:289)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.choicehotels.dbaccess.PreparedStatementProxy.execute(PreparedStatementProxy.java:225)
    at com.choicehotels.dbaccess.PreparedStatementProxy.invoke(PreparedStatementProxy.java:115)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.executeQuery(Unknown Source)

The error is because of "LIMIT ?" in the query, because if I remove it then the query runs fine. If I remove any of the "Where" conditions but keep "LIMIT ?" , the error is still thrown.

Several comments to make here, but first is that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.  What is the ORDER BY condition?

There is no ORDER BY condition. What I am trying to understand is what can be reason of having this error.

Some databases cannot parameterize the value in the LIMIT clause (DB2 is one of them). In thses cases you need to assemble/concatenate the SQL with the limit value.

It is not possible to use a ? placeholder with LIMIT.  You could rephrase your query to use ROW_NUMBER instead:
SELECT
FROM (
     SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <some_col>) rn
     FROM customer c
     WHERE acct = ? AND
           cust_id = ? AND 
           call_status = ? AND
           entry_id = get_user_id(?) AND
           cust_call_id = ? AND
           severity = ?
) t
WHERE rn <= ?;  -- bind the LIMIT value to this ?

